# How to make current page side draw bar tab highlighted in React.js

Tags: html, css, reactjs, styled-components

Here I have a side bar, *I need to highlight the selected tab*

[image: Result I need]

[image: Result I have]

I need to make the tab highlighted whenever the page changes...

How can I acheive this..?

Here is my code:

**react.js**:

```
<Menu>
        {SideBarData.map((element, i) => {
          return (
            <NavIcon onClick={showSidebar} to={element.path} key={i}>
              {element.icon}
            </NavIcon>
          );
        })}
</Menu>
```

**style.js**

```
import { Link as LinkS } from "react-router-dom";

const Menu = styled.div`
  background: ${BG_COLOR.PRIMARY_COLOR_WHITE};
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  flex: 1;
  width: 56px;
  height: 100vh;
  margin-left: -8px;
  box-shadow: 5px 0 10px -5px #888;
  position: fixed;
`;

const NavIcon = styled(LinkS)`
  font-size: ${FONT_SIZE.TEXT_NORMAL};
  display: flex;
  justify-content: flex-start;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  height: 3rem;
  width: 100%;
  color: ${BG_COLOR.PRIMARY_COLOR_BLACK};
  text-decoration: none;
  border-bottom: 1px solid;
  border-bottom-color: ${BG_COLOR.PRIMARY_COLOR_BLACK};
  text-align: left;

  &:hover {
    background-color: ${BG_COLOR.PRIMARY_COLOR};
    border-left: 5px solid ${BG_COLOR.PRIMARY_COLOR_BLACK};
    cursor: pointer;
  }
`;
```

Here I used styled-components for styling

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use NavLink by react-router-dom in your code  in this way.

```
  <NavLink to={element.path}" key={i}>
        <NavIcon>
          {element.icon}
        </NavIcon>
  </NavLink>
```

if you see your output in browser there will be an active class with on icon's parent element with current path or URL. You can add styling to that active class according to your taste

Answer (score 1):

If your sidebar is using for changing the path, you can try this feature from ReactRouter [NavLink](https://reactrouter.com/web/api/NavLink) and style the selected tab with `activeClassName`.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this using react-router-dom bu checking the path and keeping the path location as the key.

```
import { Link, withRouter } from "react-router-dom";

const CustomSider = withRouter((props) => {
  const { location } = props;

  return (
      <Menu selectedKeys={[location.pathname]} mode='inline' theme='light'>
        <Menu.Item key='/dashboard/home' icon={<HomeIcon />}>
          <Link to='/dashboard/home'>Home</Link>
        </Menu.Item>
        <Menu.Item key='/dashboard/staff' icon={<StaffIcon />}>
          <Link to='/dashboard/staff'>Staff</Link>
        </Menu.Item>
        <Menu.Item key='/dashboard/clients' icon={<ClientIcon />}>
          <Link to='/dashboard/clients'>Clients</Link>
        </Menu.Item>
        <Menu.Item key='/dashboard/calendar' icon={<CalendarIcon />}>
          <Link to='/dashboard/calendar'>Calendar</Link>
        </Menu.Item>
        <Menu.Item key='/dashboard/inventory' icon={<ToolIcon />}>
          <Link to='/dashboard/inventory'>Inventory</Link>
        </Menu.Item>
        <Menu.Item key='/dashboard/marketing' icon={<SpeakerIcon />}>
          <Link to='/dashboard/marketing'>Marketing</Link>
        </Menu.Item>
        <Menu.Item key='/dashboard/analytics' icon={<PieChartOutlined />}>
          <Link to='/dashboard/analytics'>Analytics</Link>
        </Menu.Item>
        <Menu.Item key='/dashboard/invoice' icon={<UnorderedListOutlined />}>
          <Link to='/dashboard/invoice'>Invoice/Billing</Link>
        </Menu.Item>
      </Menu>
  );
});
```

Here the react-router-dom will check the path and highlight the respective nav item.

Note: I followed this method using Ant design UI framework in React Js